# Visual Studio 2017 Freezes when I move mouse over Mat keyword (OpenCv 3.4.1)

Tags: c++, opencv

I want to develop openCv project in Visual Studio 2017. I downloaded the opencv pre-build libraries and made necessary settings. That is:

1) I added System Path `...build\x64\vc14\bin`

2) In Visual Studio from project properties I added Additional Include Directories `...opencv\build\include` under C/C++ -> General Settings

3) I added Additional Include Directories `...opencv\build\x64\vc14\lib` under Linker->General Settings

4) I added Additional Dependecies `opencv_world341d.lib` under -> Linker->Input Settings

I wrote the following code and it is compiled without an error

```
 // opencv.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
using namespace cv;

int main() {
    Mat img;
    return 0;
}
```

But the problem is when I move curser over Mat keyword after 2-3 seconds VS freezes and does not respond anyway. Do you have any idea why this happens?

Comment: That sounds like a Visual Studio IDE bug.

Comment: you should use `...build\x64\vc15\bin` and `...opencv\build\x64\vc15\lib` to begin with... Btw, I never experienced such a problem with VS2017

Comment: I tried vc15, but the problem continues.

Comment: you only linked to `opencv_world341d.lib`. I hope you linked that in debug mode only, and that you're running in debug mode. Use `opencv_world341.lib` for release. If that's correct.. as last chance I'd upgrade visual studio to the latest version

Comment: I am using in Debug mode and x64, I have the latest version of VS.

Comment: Sorry then... good luck ;)

Answer (score 3):

You can disable the Auto Quick Info option by starting at the top menu and navigating to *Tools, Options, Text Editor, C/C++,* Advanced and under IntelliSense change the value for Auto Quick Info to False.

This will turn all of the Quick Info helpers off, but will at least keep the project from freezing.

Comment: The problem should be resolved in the next update of visual studio 2017. https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/258294/freeze-while-using-quick-info-on-cvmat.html

Answer (score 3):

It seems the problem is related with VS2017, I tried on VS2015 and did not get such an error.

Answer (score 2):

It is still unfixed until 15.7.4 which was published today.

Comment: Still unfixed in 15.7.5: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51372040/hovering-over-mat-from-opencv-3-4-1-in-vs-15-7-5-still-freezes

Comment: Still unfixed in 15.7.6

Comment: Finally it has been fixed in 15.8.0

Answer (score 1):

This error is caused due to a long comment about Mat.
Look for **mat.hpp** files in your include directory of opencv (use search to find) >> go to Mat function definition >> remove the multiline comment before Mat definition.

There are two mat.hpp files in the include directory. Follow the steps in both.

Save the files. Restart Visual Studio and enjoy !!

Comment: Thanks alot, that fixed it, had same problem with GLFW/glfwCreateWindow.