# Hovering over Mat from opencv 3.4.1 in VS 15.7.5 still freezes

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencv, mat

Is anybody else still getting freezes in VS 15.7.5 while hovering over the Mat keyword in openCV 3.4.1? (note: I have included openCV 3.4.1 and the contrib modules into VS using cmake.)

Reference link to the same question but for an older version of Visual Studios:
[Link for old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50261793/visual-studio-2017-freezes-when-i-move-mouse-over-mat-keyword-opencv-3-4-1). Apparently 15.7.4 was supposed to be a fix? [Upvoted answer saying that the fix happened.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50926036/9944125)

Andrew's solution works for 15.7.5 too. [Link for temp solution.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50281369/9944125) Please take the time to give him credit.

[Screenshot for Andrew's solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vS6WT.png)

Comment: Yes, I am still having the same problem. I am using openCV 3.2.0 and VS 15.7.5

Answer (score 0):

According to [this Visual Studio thread](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/251922/vs-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8.html) it is fixed in the VS 15.8.0 preview 5. It can be found [here](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/preview/).